# Tidy up an image tag

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

i have this image tag that i'm getting from a weather source that is with errors, the output is not html but wml/wap so it crashes and burns when it shows up.
the image tag comes up like this:

```
<img alt="FACE="Monospace,Courier">LRPatches, Sky clear, Q1020</FONT><Mist, >" src="http://www.vremea.com/images/fogshow.gif"  width="50" height="50"/>
```

and i would like it to be like this:

```
<img src="http://www.vremea.com/images/fogshow.gif"  width="50" height="50"/>
```

i know i have to use `preg_replace` but I cant seem to make it work, any ideas?

Comment: You can look into tools like HTMLTidy or HTML Purifier. Whether they will parse the invalid tags the way you expect them to is questionable though, since it's pretty much undefined how invalid HTML will be parsed.

Comment: That is a quite malformed tag. Can you propose an algorithm for deducing which parts are relevant?

Comment: well i need to remove everything between <img and src, cuz the rest is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This :

```
$imgTag = '<img alt="FACE="Monospace,Courier">LRPatches, Sky clear, Q1020</FONT><Mist, >" src="http://www.vremea.com/images/fogshow.gif"  width="50" height="50"/>';
$returnValue = preg_replace('/(<img)(.*)(src.*)/', '$1 $3',$imgTag);
```

Will output :

```
'<img src="http://www.vremea.com/images/fogshow.gif"  width="50" height="50"/>'
```

Assuming your malformed `<img />` tag doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML always has the exact same syntax problem, this will work to remove anything between `<img` and `src=`. This is pretty easy to break if the HTML structure changes, but since it's broken already...

```
$html = preg_replace('/(?<=<img ).*?(?=src=)/', '', $horribleHorribleHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not tested, but this should do it.

```
<?php
$sStr = '<img ... your image>'; // your string
$iStart = strpos('src="', $sStr); // find the src
$iEnd = strpos('"', $sStr, $iStart); // find the end
$sURL = substr($sStr, $iStart, $iEnd); // get the image
echo $sURL;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to match on the attributes you want to save from your input, you can try to get the parts that look like an `<img>` tag first, and then cherry-pick the attribute looking parts of them you are interested in:

```
$input = 'some other content
    <img alt="FACE="Monospace,Courier">LRPatches, Sky clear, Q1020</FONT><Mist, >"
        src="http://www.vremea.com/images/fogshow.gif"  width="50" height="50"/>
        <span class="some"> more other content
    </span>

    <img alt="FACE="Monospace,Courier">LRPatches, Sky clear, Q1020</FONT><Mist, >"
        src="http://www.vremea.com/images/fogshow.gif"
        width="50"
        height="50"/> <span class="some"> more other content
    ';
preg_match_all('/<img.+?\/>/sim', $input, $img_parts);
foreach ($img_parts[0] as $img_part) {
    $attrs = array();
    preg_match_all('/(?<key>src|width|height)\s*=\s*"(?<value>[^"]+)/i', $img_part, $m);
    foreach ($m['key'] as $i => $key) {
        $attrs[] = "{$key}=\"{$m['value'][$i]}\"";
    }
    print "<img ".join(' ', $attrs)." />\n";
}
```

Comment: Updated with one more loop to extract the `<img>` looking parts first